# How do I invoke the Graphviz GUI from the command line?

Tags: macos, graphviz

I am looking for a way to open a DOT file (.gz or .dot) in the GUI Graphviz viewer from the command line.  So, if I run something like:

```
$ graphviz my_dot_file.gz
```

It should open the Graphviz program with the selected file. Somehow, for this simple task, my googling has failed me...

I am on Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try `dot`?

```
dot -Tx11 my_dot_file.dot
```

Comment: It is throwing a `caught SIGFPE 8` error for even the simplest graphs which open easily in the gui otherwise. I uninstalled and reinstalled graphviz using ports but that didn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: @scottmrogowski: My ability to generate ideas is restricted by lack of information. I don't even know what OS you are using, or which version of graphviz, or what the GUI you refer to is. I'd start by checking if you can create a PNG or PDF file? (Use `-Tpng -o filename.png`, or the same with `pdf` instead of `png`.) If so, the problem is with your GUI driver (maybe `x11` is wrong for your platform.) If you can't, you might have a version mismatch between the command line utility and the underlying library, or some such. Best I can do on no information.

Comment: Ah, you are correct I have not provided many details. OSX Mountain Lion. Graphviz version 2.30.1. The GUI has the same version info.  I can create pngs or pdfs or svgs or most anything else just fine using `dot`

Comment: @scottmrogowski: Thanks. You should edit your question with that information. I suppose that -Tx11 is not correct on a Mac, but I don't have one anymore so I can't really tell you what is. You can get a list of drivers with `dot -T?`; perhaps you will see something obviously maclike (quartz, maybe?). I added the `osx` tag to your question; maybe some mac expert will see it.

Comment: Complete list is: bmp canon cgimage cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps exr fig gif gv imap imap_np ismap jp2 jpe jpeg jpg pct pdf pic pict plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 psd sgi svg svgz tga tif tiff tk vml vmlz x11 xdot xlib

Answer (score 9):

You could instead render to an image and view the image:

```
$ dot -Tpng graph.dot > graph.png
$ open graph.png
```

Comment: Not totally related. It's the first I come across the `open` command line tool. And I don't have it installed on my system. Where you refering to something precise, or just something to say: `$ your-image-viewer graph.png`